# Obtaining motion vectors from raw video

Tags: algorithm, math, video, computer-vision

I'd like to know if there is any good (and freely available) text, on how to obtain motion vectors of macro blocks in raw video stream. This is often used in video compression, although my application of it is not video encoding.

Code that does this is available in OSS codecs, but understanding the method by reading the code is kinda hard.

My actual goal is to determine camera motion in 2D projection space, assuming the camera is only changing it's orientation (NOT the position). What I'd like to do is divide the frames into macro blocks, obtain their motion vectors, and get the camera motion by averaging those vectors.

I guess OpenCV could help with this problem, but it's not available on my target platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is simple brute force: Compare a macro block to each macro block from the reference frame and use the one that gives the smallest residual error. The code gets complex primarily because this is usually the slowest part of mv-based compression, so they put a lot of work into optimizing it, often at the expense of anything even approaching readability.

Especially for real-time compression, some reduce the workload a bit by (for example) restricting the search to the original position +/- some maximum delta. This can often gain quite a bit of compression speed in exchange for a fairly small loss of compression.

Comment: And then I believe the blocks are compared using a sum of absolute differences of the pixel values. Yes?

Comment: @phkahler: Some work with the absolute differences in pixels, others do the DCT and quantization first, then work with the absolute difference of coefficients. In the end, the two end up roughly equivalent though...

Comment: @jerry That's how I thought it could work, but again, this problem needs more study as I've no idea how to obtain what you call "smallest residual error". I was thinking of hashing each block in a way that allows me measuring distance between blocks, where similarity is the distance. Then finding the closest one within some spatial delta will give me the motion vector. So how could I do that?

Comment: @skrat: For a first attempt, you normally want to do what @phkahler mentions: simply walk through each block and add up the absolute values of the differences between corresponding pixels. If you can figure out a hash that'll let you properly characterize the distances, I'm pretty sure you can make enough off of that to retire. I'm not saying it can't be done, but AFAIK, no such thing is currently known.

Comment: @jerry Yes, that makes sense. If I may dig deeper, the question that bites me the most: Will I only get vectors with magnitudes equal to multiples of size of the block?

Comment: @skrat: That's pretty much up to you. MPEG works that way, but if you want to scan at every pixel instead, you certainly can (but the MPEG way is slow, and this will be a *lot* slower still).

Answer (score 0):

If you assume only camera motion, I suspect there is something possible with analysis of the FFT of successive images. For frequencies whose amplitudes have not changed much, the phase information will indicate the camera motion. Not sure if this will help with camera rotation, but lateral and vertical motion can probably be computed. There will be difficulties due to new information appearing on one edge and disappearing on the other and I'm not sure how much that will hurt. This is speculative thinking in response to your question, so I have no proof or references :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing a very limited [SLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping) project?

Lots of reading matter at [Bristol University](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Research/Vision/Realtime/index.html), [Imperial College](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ajd/), [Oxford University](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~mobile/wikisite/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Publications.SLAM) for example - you might find their approaches to finding and matching candidate features from frame to frame of interest - much more robust than simple sums of absolute differences.

Answer (score 0):

For the most low-level algorithms of this type the term you are looking for is [optical flow](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Optical_flow) and one of the easiest algorithms of that class is the [Lucas Kanade algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_Optical_Flow_Method).

[This](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCEQFjAB&url=http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~mcoimbra/lectures/VCS_0708/VCS%25202008%2520-%252010%2520-%2520Optical%2520Flow.pdf&ei=QQ-nTYb3O9GbOonblNIJ&usg=AFQjCNEx4s1UYHFIe_FNAQH5hB5cREvcQg&sig2=XOmp-MwiVp3I0C-RLRiOjg) is a pretty good overview presentation that should give you plenty of ideas for an algorithm that does what you need